# Option to get number of topic subscribers in kafka-producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Is there any option to find number of subscribers for a particular topic in kafka-producer [ KafkaProducer] ?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Producers and Consumers are completely decoupled. There is no API in the producer to find what consumers exist.

You could build something by yourself following the design of `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` -- just dig through the code; it's all open source.

Comment: After long gap, again I need number of subscribers in producer side. How to dig through the code.Is there any other link or tutorial is there to gone through the code?

Comment: For producers, there is no tracking whatsoever... If you really need to know this, the only way would be to lock at broker logs, but that's of course no solution you want to build into any application, but for debugging only.